# android gradle plugin 4.2.0: Connection Reset

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio, but when I try to create a new project. Gradle version 6.7.1 is installed well, but the Gradle plugin 4.2.0 is not, This error popup. I tried many things even VPN, turn off antivirus, and firewall. but I couldn't solve this problem. I post the error below. Thanks.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.0/gradle-4.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.0/gradle-4.2.0.pom'.
               > Connection reset

    ... 243 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    ... 258 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .gradle folder from your home_folder. Then, sync your project again
The gradle cache is located at

```
On Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches
On Mac / UNIX: ~/.gradle/caches/
```

Additionally, try mavenCentral() to your repositories like below and see if it fixes your issue?

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

If none worked, you please share your project and app’s Gradle file

Comment: Thanks, Akki I did what you suggest, I delete the .gradle folder and try to sync again. but the same error happen.

Comment: Did you already added mavenCentral() as suggested? This repo should have the gradle plugin. Else you could also try to add below in your repositories: 
maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
Also, see if you put have “jcenter() put above “maven” in your gradle. If it is, then try once by putting “jcenter” after “maven”.
Also, check if you are working offline and uncheck it.
It would be better if you could share your gradle files.